# How to get DB result without using GET method?

Tags: php, hyperlink

Well, I don't know how this question should be called like but I'm wondering how websites like e.g. bit.ly work.

I mean - when I shorten my link I get a result:

```
bit.ly/**e1x2a3m4p5l6e** not GET method used here.
```

I know how to get an effect like `bit.ly?id=e1x2a3m4p5l6e` (GET method) but I don't know how to get an effect like above.

Comment: google for `mod_rewrite`

Comment: What do you mean with "no GET method used"? Looking at the network tab of Chrome dev tools when opening your example bitly URL reveals a HTTP GET request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can essentially do this 2 ways:

**The .htaccess route with mod_rewrite**

Add a file called `.htaccess` in your root folder, and add something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?Some-text-goes-here/([0-9]+)$ /picture.php?id=$1
```

This will tell Apache to enable mod_rewrite for this folder, and if it gets asked a URL matching the regular expression it rewrites it internally to what you want, without the end user seeing it. Easy, but inflexible, so if you need more power:

**The PHP route**

Put the following in your .htaccess instead: (note the leading slash)

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

This will tell it to run your index.php for all files it cannot normally find in your site. In there you can then for example:

```
$path = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');    // Trim leading slash(es)
$elements = explode('/', $path);                // Split path on slashes
if(empty($elements[0])) {                       // No path elements means home
    ShowHomepage();
} else switch(array_shift($elements))             // Pop off first item and switch
{
    case 'Some-text-goes-here':
        ShowPicture($elements); // passes rest of parameters to internal function
        break;
    case 'more':
        ...
    default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
        Show404Error();
}
```

This is how big sites and CMS-systems do it, because it allows far more flexibility in parsing URLs, config and database dependent URLs etc. For sporadic usage the hardcoded rewrite rules in `.htaccess` will do fine though.

Comment: Thank you for comprehensive explanation!